# Maven stuck downloading maven-default-http-blocker

Tags: maven

I'm building a provided Google Dataflow template [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates). So I'm running the command:

```sh
mvn compile exec:java \
-Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.<template-class> \
-Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false \
-Dexec.args=" \
--project=<project-id> \
--stagingLocation=gs://<bucket-name>/staging \
--tempLocation=gs://<bucket-name>/temp \
--templateLocation=gs://<bucket-name>/templates/<template-name>.json \
--runner=DataflowRunner"
```

However, it seems the compile is stuck downloading `maven-default-http-blocker`. The log I have after adding `-X` is:

```
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata io.grpc:grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml in local (/Users/bli00/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for io.grpc:grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded/maven-metadata.xml in local (/Users/bli00/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for confluent (http://packages.confluent.io/maven/).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for ow2-snapshot (http://repository.ow2.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for repository.jboss.org (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for m2.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for m2.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for glassfish-repository (http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for maven2-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for m1.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/1).
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for sonatype-nexus-snapshots (http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots).
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata net.minidev:json-smart/maven-metadata.xml in local (/Users/bli00/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for net.minidev:json-smart/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date
[DEBUG] net.minidev:json-smart/maven-metadata.xml was not found in https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not be reattempted until the update interval of apache.snapshots.https has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for http://0.0.0.0/
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://0.0.0.0/
Downloading from maven-default-http-blocker: http://0.0.0.0/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml
```

Not sure how maven works but I've tried `mvn clean` and rerunning. And I'm assuming `0.0.0.0` is my local cache? Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: It looks like you may have a proxy set up or something else is going on network wise. It's also possible you have a Maven issue. ... What's your version?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting from Maven 3.8.1, http repositories are blocked.

You need to either configure them as mirrors in your `settings.xml` or replace them by https repositories (if those exist).

Comment: Theres no settings.xml in the repository and I havent configured any proxy. Is there a global settings.xml?

Comment: settings.xml is usually put into the user directory under `.m2`. You can write one if you don't have one. You can also read it from somewhere else with command line option `-s`. A temporary workaround would be to use Maven 3.6.3.

Comment: Thankyou. I have used 3.6.3 successfully. I will contact the authors of the relevant repository and suggest they upgrade to https.

Comment: @bli00 yes, you may be able to disable this behaviour by editing the global settings.xml. For Maven 3.8.5 installed with Homebrew, it is located at `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.5/libexec/conf/settings.xml`.